# hyperref overfull box

Tags: hyperref, thesis

Sometimes using `hyperref` can produce overfull boxes because `hyperref` does not seem to allow its hyperlinks to be broken into multiple lines[image]

For exampled the italicized text in the highlighted bibliography entry contains a hyperlink which may be broken into two lines. How do I make it happen?

I can't use pdflatex as I am using eps images. Using XeLaTeX produces figures at arbitrary places as shown below:

[image: Figure at wrong place]

I think this happens due to a conflict of packages that I have. These are all the packages that I am currently using:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, fontsize=12, toc=listof, toc=bib]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm, outer=2cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{natmove}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

Only pdf chain produces the correct output except for the overfull hyperlinks ofcourse.

Comment: Are you using `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf` by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I use 'latex + dvips + ps2pdf'.

Comment: hyperref can break links if you use pdflatex

Comment: Can't use pdflatex. Question edited.

Answer (score 2):

From `hyperref`'s [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf):

> ### Wrapped/broken link support
>
> Only few drivers support automatically wrapped/broken links,
>   e.g. `pdftex`, `dvipdfm`, `hypertex`. Other
>   drivers lack this   feature, e.g. `dvips`, `dvipsone`.
>
> Workarounds:
>
> - For long section or caption titles in the table of contents
>     or list of figures/tables option `linktocpage` can be used.
>     Then the page number will be a link, and the overlong section
>     title is not forced into an one line link with overvull `\hbox`
>     warning.
> - `\url`s are caught by package `breakurl`.
> - The option `breaklinks` is intended for internal use. But it
>     can be used to force link wrapping, e.g. when printing a
>     document. However, when such a document is converted to PDF
>     and viewed with a PDF viewer, the active link area will be
>     misplaced.
>
>   Another limitation: some penalties are "optimized" by TeX,
>     thus there are missing break points, especially within
>     `\url`. (See thread "hyperref.sty, breaklinks and url.sty 3.2"
>     in `comp.text.tex` 2005-09).

Comment: What's the syntax of using breakurl. Because \usepackage{breakurl} does not seem to be working. Other options in the documentation, like anythingbreaks, are too extreme.

Comment: @DKS: Package `breakurl`'s main point are URLs. `\url` is redefined by default, also `\burl` can be used. There is also `\burlalt`, see the documentation of package `burl`. I cannot say anything to the example, because a minimal example file is missing that would show, what is a link and how it is generated.